# Custom cursor only shows briefly

Tags: html, css, cursor, cursors

In my project I use custom cursors, but those only show up for maybe a second and go back to the normal cursor. The elements are not overlaid by anything (Made sure of that with "pointer-events: none;" on overlaying elements).

Here is the CSS I'm using to apply those custom cursors:

```
.plant {
    -webkit-cursor: url("../img/watering_can.png"), auto;
    cursor: url("../img/watering_can.png"), auto;
}
```

or just:

```
.pointer {
    -webkit-cursor: pointer;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The content is mostly generated dynamically from an object.
The DOM looks something like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104966260/DOM.png

e.g. should the "kitchen sink" element have a pointer, because it has the class "pointer"

Comment: Can you provide some HTML?